# ¿Como imprimir si o no en ves de boolean (true ;false) JAVA

Tags: java, bucle-for, booleano

Bueno he creado la instancia y todo eso solo quiero saber como imprimir si o no en ves de boolean, le dejo mi codigo

```
public class Datos {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Futbolistas futbolistas =new Futbolistas("Lenin", "", true, true);
    Futbolistas[] fut = new Futbolistas[5];

    fut[0]=new Futbolistas("Lenin", "Castillo", true, true); 
    fut[1]=new Futbolistas("Dya", "Castillo", true, true); 
    fut[2]=new Futbolistas("Rocj", "Castillo", true, true); 
    fut[3]=new Futbolistas("Ronaldn", "Castillo", true, true); 
    fut[4]=new Futbolistas("Lionel", "Messi", true, true);         


            for (int i = 0; i < fut.length; i++) {

    //Aqui se empieza pero no se como poner para imprimir si o no 
    if (fut[i].isFamoso()==true) {
        System.out.println("Si");

    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
       System.out.println(fut[i].getNombre()+fut[i].getApellido()+
               fut[i].isFamoso()+fut[i].isLesion()); 

    }
}   
}
```

Debería crear otra variable para poder leer y asi convertir en si o no?
Ejemplo ese

```
 String verificar = fut[i].isFamoso();
```

Comment: No se entiende bien la duda. El método `isFamoso` ya retorna un `boolean` y con eso puedes saber si es famoso o no.

Comment: Lo que ya te han dicho: No se entiende tu pregunta. Si lo que quieres es que isFamoso retorne un String con la palabra "Si" o "No", pues tendrás que cambiar la función para que en vez de retornar un boolean retorne un String, y dentro de la función retornar "Si" o "No" tras la comprobación que hagas ahora para retornar true o false. Si se da la condición en la que retornabas true, retornas "Si" y "No" en otro caso. Pero esto lo veo tan básico que entiendo que no es a lo que te refieres. Porque si se trata de esto te recomiendo que te leas el manual de java que no parece que hayas leído.

Comment: Así estaría bien, ya que si ` isFamoso()` devuelve `true`, saldrá por consola "si", y si es `false` saldrá "no". Ahora, como consejo, es redundante decir `if (fut[i].isFamoso()==true)` ya que `isFamoso()` es una expresión `booleana`, por lo tanto basta con decir `if (fut[i].isFamoso())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el método `isFamoso()` devuelve un booleano, y en el contexto que muestras quieres imprimir `Sí` o `No` según el caso, puedes usar un ternario, por ejemplo:

```
//Definimos una variable para guardar el resultado de la evaluación
String mOutput="";
for (int i = 0; i < fut.length; i++) {
    //Aqui se empieza pero no se como poner para imprimir si o no 
    mOutput = (fut[i].isFamoso()) ? "Sí" : "No";
    System.out.println(mOutput);

    //Resto del código
}
```

El operador ternario en este caso es como un `if` comprimido, evalúa el resultado de `fut[i].isFamoso()`, si es `true` la variable adquiere el valor `Sí`, de lo contrario adquiere el valor `No`. Pero no se queda ahí, es una herramienta mucho más potente, con la cual puedes hacer comparaciones anidadas y mucho más. Para más detalles puedes consultar [*Ternary Operator In Java*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator).

Si es una cosa que vas a usar a gran escala, podrías también dotar a tu clase de un método que retorne un `Sí` o  `No` en vez de un booleano. Ese método haría lo mismo que `isFamoso()`, pero retornaría sí o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa es la respuesta que necesitaba. Me alegro que usted entendió bien mi pregunta. Le agradezco mucho